# C# Encrypt data AES

Tags: c#, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt data with AES? I'd love to use at least 128 Bits for the encryption Key.

I tried with AES default class provided by Microsoft but I can't do a lot... I can't set the Key Lenght.

Is there  another Class that I can use?

Comment: http://yossi-yakubov.blogspot.co.id/2010/07/aes-encryption-using-c-short-way.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the code listed at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt

You Can Use `RIJNDAEL`:

First you need to include `using System.Security.Cryptography;`

```
public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

        // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
        // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return decryptedBytes;
    }


public void EncryptFile(string filename, string outfilename, string psw)
        {
            string file = filename;
            string password = psw;

            byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(file); //read bytes to encrypt them 
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password); //read with UTF8 encoding the password.
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes); //hash the psw

            byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

            string fileEncrypted = outfilename;

            File.WriteAllBytes(fileEncrypted, bytesEncrypted);
        }
        public void DecryptFile(string filename, string outfilename, string psw)
        {
            string fileEncrypted = filename;
            string password = psw;

            byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(fileEncrypted);
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            byte[] bytesDecrypted = AES_Decrypt(bytesToBeDecrypted, passwordBytes);

            string file = outfilename;
            File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytesDecrypted);
        }
```

Comment: It is important to note that `AES.BlockSize = 128;` is key, this is what makes  `Rijndael` AES.

Comment: @zaph Yes! Thank you... What do you think about the code? Is it ok?

Comment: The scheme looks good, the key is derived from the password correctly, the CBC mode is fine, there is an assumption about the padding that I would be happier if it was explicit in the code. There is no check that the correct decryption key is used but you many not need that, if you do encryption authentication would need to be added. I do not know C# so can't comment on that.